# Angular: passing object through bindToController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created the following element directive:

```
    orderApp.directive('addressBlock', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            bindToController: {
                addressType: '@',
                address: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '/pages/address-block.html',
            controllerAs: 'AddressCtrl',
            controller: 'AddressController'
        };
    });
```

Now I want to access addressType and address values in AddressController. I created basic function to check that values are passing through:

```
  orderApp.controller('AddressController', function(){

    console.log(this);

 });
```

The thing is that "addressType" is correct while "address" is undefined.

Here is how I define directive in HTML:

```
<address-block address-type="Ship" address="orderCtrl.order.shippingAddress"></address-block>
```

Did I miss something? Or there are any special ways to pass object data?

---

UPDATE

I have found out what was wrong with the code. The thing is that we initialise orderCtrl.order property with data we received from server with $http get.

This request takes  some time and during this time the following code will have this.address undefined.

```
  orderApp.controller('AddressController', function(){

       console.log(this);

  });
```

Once data is received form server this.address will contain actual data.

Thank to everyone for help!

Comment: may i know what version of angular are you using

Comment: @jkris it's AngularJS v1.4.8

Comment: Does orderCtrl.order.shippingAddress exist?

Comment: Isn't bindToController just a boolean? From angular docs: "`bindToController: true` will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller"

Comment: @KostyaShkryob yes it used to be just a boolean, but they upgraded it in v1.4

Comment: @Tamara, code doesn't seem to be wrong, here's a quick fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/9ocza4wL/1/

Comment: @jkris thank you for fiddle, your example works. I guess I found issue in my code and will add update